# How to write mongodb positions insert query

Tags: mongodb

I am newbie to the mongodb. I would like to insert positions[lon and lat]  values [51.5625,7.9865] for the Address fields in all document who has postalCode=22222. How Can I do that?  Please let me know db query statement.

```
db.user.find({"address.postalCode":"222222"})
```

Above query fetches 10 documents from my db.

Sample Address object from my user collection

```
"address" : {
        "_id" : "7783-hsdh-7878-halkad-8989-lksdlk",
        "address" : "Department of State",
        "city" : "Washington",
        "stateProvince" : "Washington, DC",
        "postalCode" : "20521",
        "country" : "USA"
    },
```

So, Result should be

```
"address" : {
        "_id" : "7783-hsdh-7878-halkad-8989-lksdlk",
        "address" : "Department of State",
        "city" : "Washington",
        "stateProvince" : "Washington, DC",
        "postalCode" : "20521",
        "country" : "USA",
        "position" : [ 
           51.5625, 7.9865
         ]
    },
```

Comment: Newbies should start reading the basic [tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/applications/crud/). Where after a little "practice" you will find wonderous things like [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). Plenty of resources out there for you to learn these things from. Start loooking for them and using them rather than just expecting someone to provide you with immediate answers to things that are easy to find. Welcome to StackOverflow. We do expect you to make some basic effort, and when you do ( this shows no effort ) then we will help.

Comment: Right, its obvious, we're following mongo doc, but it doesn't find helpful for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find the document, modify the value, **markModified**, then save.

```
db.user.find({"address.postalCode":"222222"}, function(err, usrs){
    for(var i = 0; i < usrs.length; i ++) {
        usrs[i].address.position = [51.5625,7.9865];
        usrs[i].markModified("address");
        usrs[i].save();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. Giving error: error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: ", "code" : 13097 }

Comment: @user4567570 You accepted this answer 2 days ago, and now it is giving error... Did you changed anything? If yes, what do you change? If no, do it running well before and giving error now? It seems like you query are invalid.

Comment: @user4567570 Where did this error appear? is `save()` reporting this error, or is `find` reporting this error? Or, is `markModified` reporting this error?

Comment: I apologized, but it never worked for me. I am simply executing this for save, gives error.

Comment: 王庭茂 - Could you please update me with correct answer?